# C# and Active Directory : test if an OU exist

Tags: c#, active-directory

How can i Test if and Organizational Unit Exists in Active Directory before creating it with C# ?

Comment: **What have you tried?**

Comment: try{DirectoryEntry Ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://192.168.0.1/Users", Login, Pass);} and catch an eventual exception ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a `.Exists()` method on the `DirectoryEntry` which you can use - assuming you have the **correct** LDAP path for your OU!

```
if (DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://" + objectPath))
{
   // ......
}
```

Your main problem will be: the path you're using is **wrong** - the `Users` is a **generic container** and thus needs to be addressed like this:

```
LDAP://192.168.0.1/CN=Users
```

Note the `CN=` prefix. If you had an actual organizational unit, it would have to be prefixed with `OU=`

For a great resource, check out [Howto: (almost) everything in Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#)

Comment: and using `PrincipalContext` ?