# How do I determine if an OU exists using C#'s System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

While [C# and Active Directory : test if an OU exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767966/c-sharp-and-active-directory-test-if-an-ou-exist) is a useful example, C# appears to be moving away from the `System.DirectoryServices` functionality to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` as it provides a nicer and cleaner syntax.

I'm currently have some code where the only use of `DirectoryEntry` is to determine if an OU exists.  Is it possible to determine if an OU exists without using `DirectoryEntry`, instead just using the `Principal`-based functionality?

Comment: FWIW the answer appears to be no, looking at the .NET Core's implementation of the AccountManagement classes.

Comment: What information do you know about the OU (`distinguishedName` or just the name)?

Comment: Keep in mind that the `AccountManagement` namespace just uses `DirectoryEntry` in the background anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The following will test whether or not an OU exists using a `PrincipalContext` object.

```
try
{ 
    var ou = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, targetedDcUrl, container);            
    var searchPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(ou);
    var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(searchPrincipal);

    var users = searcher.FindAll();
}
catch (PrincipalOperationException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Container does not exist");
}
```

The accessing of the OU when searching (or any other action that requires a read/write to the domain) will cause an exception.

Comment: This is an indirect method, so not accepting it as _the_ answer in case someone has a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The [documentation for the `AccountManagement` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement) starts off with:

> The System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace provides uniform access and manipulation of user, computer, and group security principals

Note that it says nothing of OUs. They didn't design it for that.

In LDAP in general, the quickest way to test whether an object exists is to bind directly to the object. That is exactly what `DirectoryEntry.Exists()` does. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices/DirectoryEntry.cs):

```
/// <devdoc>
/// Searches the directory store at the given path to see whether an entry exists.
/// </devdoc>        
public static bool Exists(string path)
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path);
    try
    {
        entry.Bind(true);       // throws exceptions (possibly can break applications) 
        return entry.Bound;
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
    {
        if (e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80072030) ||
             e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80070003) ||   // ERROR_DS_NO_SUCH_OBJECT and path not found (not found in strict sense)
             e.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x800708AC))     // Group name could not be found
            return false;
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        entry.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Any other way of doing it will perform worse.

Kind of a side note: while the `AccountManagement` namespace makes some things easier for the developer, it comes at a cost. It always performs worse than using `DirectoryEntry` directly. Sometimes it's not noticeable, but if you're doing a lot of lookups, it can add up fast.